# Click a link on page unload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onunload

I have multiple forms in one page, each of them with their unique save action.

I want to implement an "auto-save" feature and my idea, when user navigates away without saving its form, it's to catch the page unload event and click on the existing save buttons.

Here's the piece of JS code:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(){
  $('#saveLink').click();
  console.log('Save link clicked.');
}, false);
```

I got all console logs written, but none of the links are clicked.

What may be wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling the function that is triggered by click event instead of just triggering the click event.

Comment: Since I don't have access to the function names ('cause they're generated by the platform I'm using), I'll try to eval() the "onclick" attribute of the link.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. Could this be related to the fact that the function that I want to call does an AJAX call?